# Change image when button is pressed and then have image return to original after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I am new to Swift. I am learning it via video tutorials step by step. However with each tutorial I attempt to make very simple apps to re-enforce what I am learning, and I am moving slowly so I can retain what I am learning.

Down to my question! I have created a very simple app that is no more than a button laid over an image and when the button is pressed the image changes. You then press the reset button and it goes back to the original image. What I want is for the user to press the button then have the image change and 5 seconds later it auto changes back to the original image, "no reset button" for the user to have to press. How can I do this, in a very simple way?

FYI I have several buttons on the screen so I will want to do this for each button individually at this time, as I learn more I will revisit this project and learn to create a single function that I can just call anytime I want to do this, that way creating cleaner code. But I got to walk before I run.

Ok, so here is what my current code looks like.  How do I add this into it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var bkgrdImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var yellowDesktopImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var greenDesktopImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var yellowExpanded: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var greenExpanded: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var yellowButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var greenButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func learnYellow(sender: AnyObject) {
        bkgrdImage.hidden = false


   yellowDesktopImage.hidden = true
    greenDesktopImage.hidden = true
    yellowExpanded.hidden = false
    greenExpanded.hidden = true
    yellowButton.hidden = true
    greenButton.hidden = true 
}
```

---

So where/how do i add this piece of code?

```
imageView.image = newImage //change to the new image

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    imageView.image = originalImage //change back to the old image after 5 sec
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate you , can you show ur tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this in your button press function should do the job:

Above the class, `import Dispatch`

```
imageView.image = newImage //change to the new image

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    imageView.image = originalImage //change back to the old image after 5 sec
});
```

Comment: You could also use NSTimer

Comment: more admin with an NSTimer imo

Comment: True, its better if you want to run a function after a certain amount of time especially if you want to repeat

Comment: Ok, so here is what my current code looks like.  How do I add this into it?

Comment: So I have updated my question to include my code.  Can you tell me how to add in the code listed above to mine so that I can make this work?

Comment: it would go inside your `learnYellow` function, and im not entirely sure what all those variables are doing, but i think you would change `bkgrdImage` to a new image, then in the dispatch_after change it back to the original.